# Objects disappearing in render

Tags: rendering

"restrict render" is on. Layers are checked.Materials checked
No idea why they do not show

[image]

Blend file: [image]

Comment: weird. if you unparent the head it comes back into rendering... it must be something in the (quite complex) rigging behaviour... but can't spot what, atm.

Comment: One more thing: When I switch to blender render, it it's normal again @@

Comment: That armature is completely screwed. I tried to append that armature to a default file and it hides (in cycles) also the default cube... Delete it and build a new one...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why, but something in your rigging is to blame here.
When I removed the head object's parenting to the armature, it popped back into existence.

[image]